# Trying to pass a value to another page with localStorage.setItem and JQuery not working - what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a part of the page which showcases the details of a task with a button on it that should redirect the user to the Edit page (`Izmeni zadatak`):

```
<div id="buttonwrapperdetalji">
        <button type="submit" class="dugmedetalji" name="button" onclick="izvrsiZadatak(); filtriraj();">Poništi zadatak</button>
        <form action="izmeni.php">
        <button type="submit" class="dugmedetalji" name="button2" onclick="izmeni();">Izmeni zadatak</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function izmeni() {
        let zadatak = <?=$podaci->zadatakID?>;
        localStorage.setItem("id", zadatak);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Now, when I open the Edit page, or `izmeni.php`, I want to automatically set the value of a select tag to the `id` that was forwarded with `localStorage.setItem` :

```
<div class="containerwrapper">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container_izmena">
            <div id = "levo">
            <h4>Zadatak</h4>
            <select id="zadatak" name="zadatak" onchange="prikazi(this.value); popuniDetalje();"required></select>
            </div>

[...]

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>  
    function popuniZadatke() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../funkcije/popuniZadatke.php',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#zadatak").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    popuniZadatke();

    function izaberi() {
        $("#zadatak").val(localStorage.getItem("id")).change();
    }
    izaberi();

</script>
```

This is what the `popuniZadatke.php` code looks like:

```
<?php
require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
require "../modeli/zadatak.php";

$zadaci = Zadatak::vratiZadatkeZaOpcije($konekcija);

?>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden><?= "Zadaci" ?> </option>
<?php

foreach ($zadaci as $zad) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $zad->zadatakID ?>"><?= $zad->naziv ?> </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The function `izaberi()`  should be setting it to the forwarded value but that doesn't seem to be working. What is the problem here?

Comment: Try to console.log(localStorage.getItem("id")) and see if you need to parse it or it's undefined value

Comment: I'm seeing the proper value in the console, i.e. the ID of the task that was picked

Comment: Okay great then try to put a static value here
`$("#zadatak").val('staticValue').change()` ... If it's worked then try to put this in the begging of the script `var id = localStorage.getItem("id") and send your var to the function, if it's didn't work then make sure your selected element is not undefined, console.log($("#zadatak"))

Comment: What should `$("#zadatak").val('staticValue').change()` do to see if it's working?

Comment: It will change your select option to staticValue in your case replace staticValue with the stored id in your local storage ... $("#zadatak").val('typeYourIDHereManual').change()

Comment: That probably seems to be the problem, it's not working. The ID of the task is 17, so I tried putting it in as `$("#zadatak").val("17).change();` and it's not doing anything. When I try to `console.log($("#zadatak"))` I get `.fn.init(1)`

Comment: Try to move this function izaberi() inside the success ajax after changing the html of the node

Comment: This was the problem, thank you so much!

Comment: Good that work , Happy to hear

Answer (score 0):

`izaberi` executes before the success function of the ajax call occurs, so the changes it makes to `#zadatak` are overwritten by `$("#zadatak").html(data)`.

I suggest you call izaberi from within the success function:

```
function popuniZadatke() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../funkcije/popuniZadatke.php',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#zadatak").html(data);
            izaberi();
        }
    });
}
popuniZadatke();

function izaberi() {
    $("#zadatak").val(localStorage.getItem("id")).change();
}
//izaberi();
```